# Difficulty achieving the desired output configuration

Tags: output-formatting

In order to describe the associated issues please see code sample below. The code presented is a simplified to include only whats needed as to better communicate the problems at hand.

Following code creates a sample data set to be used for visualization purposes:

```
(*Simulated data*)
f = RandomReal[{1*10^-5, 1*10^-3}, 20];
q = RandomReal[{4, 20}, 20];
```

After variables `f` and `q` have been set, the data is `preprocess` and `posprocess` to retrieve the necessary information:

```
(*Process data*)
preprocess = Sort@Transpose[{q, f}];
posprocess = Reverse@Accumulate@Reverse@preprocess[[All, 2]];
```

Given the above steps have been carried out, `complete` data set is generated below:

```
(*Data*)
complete  = Table[AppendTo[preprocess[[i]], posprocess[[i]]],{i,Length@posprocess}];
```

In order to visualise the above, I was looking to develop an interface which would include three [Column](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html)'s containing the information held within `complete` data set. Additionally, in a [Row](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html?q=Row) form, the second [Item](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Item.html?q=Item) was meant to be a [ListLogPlot[*list*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html). Following is the code of the  implementation:

```
(*Output*)
Framed@Row[{
   Pane[
    Grid[{
      Style[#, Bold, Darker[Blue], "Courier", 16] & /@ {"q'", "f", 
        "\[CapitalSigma]f"},
      Column[#, Center] & /@ ScientificForm@# & /@ 
       Table[complete[[All, i]], {i, 3}]
      }],
    Scrollbars -> {False, True}, ImageSize -> {320, 300}
    ],
   ListLogPlot[complete[[All, 3]],
    AxesLabel -> Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ {"\[CapitalSigma]f", "q'"},
    PlotRange -> {#@complete[[All, 1]] & /@ {Min, Max}, Automatic},
    ImageSize -> {500, 320}]
   }]
```

The above code works and produces the interface which I hoped to implement. However, there is a set of issues releted to the above implementation which I hope someone could assist to resolve:

1. When applying [ScientificForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html), the content of the columns becomes misaligned. This can be reproduced by increasing the sample space (Ex. 20)
2. [AxesLabel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html?q=AxesLabel) does not display label for 'X' axis
3. [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html?q=PlotRange) does not display all data points. This can be reproduced by reducing the sample space (Ex. 5)
4. With small sample space (Ex. 5), clicking on [Scroolbar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scrollbars.html) makes [Column](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html)
   data disapear

Comments and suggestions relevent to the above subject matter are welcome. Ideally, I am looking to resolve the identified issues or receive pointers towards the documentations which could assist in doing so.

Comment: Could someone please elaborate on the reason why question has been down-voted and voted for close? I'd appreciate feedback so I can improve quality of my questions in future.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I voted to close because the problems are readily solved by consulting the documentation and the numerous examples therein

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch your comment is valuable. I did consult documentation and searched forum before posting a question. I will make sure to spend more time on the available resources in future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grid =
 Grid[Prepend[complete, 
    Style[#, Bold, Darker[Blue], "Courier", 16] & /@ {"q'", "f", "\[CapitalSigma]f"}],
   Alignment -> Right] /. x_Real /; x < 1 :> ScientificForm@x;

plot =
 ListLogPlot[
  complete[[All, 3]],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ {"\[CapitalSigma]f", "q'"}),
  PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> {500, 320}];

Framed@Row[{
   Pane[
    grid,
    Scrollbars -> {False, True},
    ImageSize -> {320, 300}],
   plot}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Re. 2 Use this:

```
AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ {"\[CapitalSigma]f", "q'"})
```

or

```
AxesLabel -> Map[Style[#, Bold, 12] &, {"\[CapitalSigma]f", "q'"}]
```

This requirement for this can be found by double-clicking twice on the original `Style` which will show that the rule take precedence over the map.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Alignment -> {Left, Top}` within `Grid` and `Column`
2. Use `AxesLabel->{Style["\[CapitalSigma]f", Bold, 12], Style["q'", Bold, 12]}` explicitly
3. Use `PlotRange -> All`
4. same as #1

Some quick changes that can help:

```
Framed@Column[{
   Pane[
    Grid[
     Join[{Style[#, Bold, Darker[Blue], "Courier", 16] & /@ {"q'", 
         "f", "\[CapitalSigma]f"}},
      Map[ScientificForm, complete, {2}]
      ],
     Alignment -> {Left, Top}],
    Scrollbars -> {False, True}, ImageSize -> {320, 300}, 
    Alignment -> {Left, Top}], 
   ListLogPlot[complete[[All, 3]], 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["\[CapitalSigma]f", Bold, 12], 
      Style["q'", Bold, 12]}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> {500, 320}]}]
```